# How to use multiple links in bootsrap-4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I actually downloaded a bootstrap-4 template for UI. I'm currently customizing it for my use. Here I want to add some Modal pop-ups to the page, I referred `W3schools` for the code where there are some links for CSS and JS but if I just copy-pasting it to my template it changes the appearance. The problem is because my template already has some reference links for the page itself so when I'm adding anything extra it changes the existing structure. Where should I add it to keep the same code without changing the already existing structure?

I tried pasting at the top and bottom of the code but by doing so it changes the appearance of the entire page. I even tried using the code without these links it's working but the modal box is not styled properly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Centered Modal Example</h2>
  <p>Center the modal vertically and horizontally within the page, with the .modal-dialog-centered class.</p>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Do I have to include all these links? Please help me add the code without changing the existing style.

Comment: The code segment above appears to work correctly when pasted in its entirety into a new html document.  What are you asking, how to add this in to your exisiting code?

Comment: refer this [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/)